# Constraints on q for q-ary lattices?

Tags: lattice-crypto, prime-numbers, safe-prime

In lattice cryptography, people often work with q-ary lattices so that we can use the hardness of short integer solution (SIS) and learning with errors (LWE). I saw in some notes that sometimes we want $q$ to be prime or a prime power. However there wasn't any explanation to why that is the case. So I have a couple of questions about the choice of $q$:

1. Is there any issues with taking q to be any positive integer? Or are there any values that have shown to be problematic?
2. What's the advantage of choosing it to be prime or a prime power? And are there any primes that are better suited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hilder mentions, via the technique of "modulus switching" the particular choice of $q$ does not matter much for the security of LWE.
Therefore, the particular form of $q$ is mostly to enable efficiency improvements.
I'm the wrong person to exhaustively list all of them, but one can easily point to a few by reading the NIST PQC KEM proposals.

For example:

1. Choosing $q = 2^k$ for some $k$ allows one to replace modular reductions by $q$ with bit shifts, a cheaper operation. This is part of the reason that Saber chooses $q = 2^{13}$.
2. Choosing $q$ to be "NTT Friendly". The NTT is a certain analogue of the FFT "mod $q$" (rather than over $\mathbb{C}$) that can enable large speedups in polynomial multiplications (roughly from $O(n^2)$ naive complexity to $O(n\log n)$). The size of the speedup is directly linked to having a suitable analogue of $i\in\mathbb{C}$. The best case (say when working over $\mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(x^n+1)$ for $n = 2^k$) happens when you have a "primitive $2n$th root of unity", which happens when $q\equiv 1\bmod 2n$ (I think). Note that this is not compatible with the prior optimization. The KEM Kyber makes this choice (almost, there are small technical differences).
3. Choosing $q$ to be a product of small (word-size) coprimes, so one can appeal to the Chinese Remainder theorem, and keep all arithmetic word-size. I don't know of a KEM that does this, but this is popular in the FHE literature (and often goes by the name "Residue Number System", or RNS arithmetic).

So there are arguments for choosing $q \equiv 0 \bmod 2^k$, $q\equiv 1\bmod 2\times 2^k$, and $q$ a product of small coprimes. These may all seem to be mutually exclusive optimizations, but one can be somewhat clever and use multiple optimizations at once.
For example, there is [this work](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1397.pdf) on embedding arithmetic mod $2^k$ (i.e. "modular reduction friendly") into an NTT friendly ring, letting one use both optimizations 1 and 2.

Comment: For the LWE, the form of $q$ is irrelevant, and I would guess that this is also the case for SIS, as these two problems are closely related. However, as I wrote in my answer, using the LWE to SIS reduction just gives us a definitive answer for a set of the SIS instances, not for the SIS in general. But, for example, how can we prove that SIS with $\beta=n^4=\omega(q)$ is secure regardless the form of q?

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but may already be useful...

[It is known](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/258.pdf) that only the bit length but not the form of $q$ is important for the security of the LWE (and the RLWE) problem.

Moreover, if we can solve $SIS_{n, q, \beta}$ with $\beta = O(q / \sigma)$, then we can solve $LWE_{n, q, \sigma}$ (see Corollary 2 of [[MPS15]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/046.pdf#page=15)).

Thus, at least for such small bound $\beta$ on the norm of the SIS solutions, the form of $q$ should not matter.